# Mongoose increment operator increasing count by two

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently, I am trying to increment a count by one through this function :

```
Goal.updateOne({_id: goalID, 'participants.userID': uid}, {$inc: {'participants.$.streak': 1}}, {}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return socket.error(err)
    } else {
        return
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});;
```

Essentially, it finds the goal that has a participant with the kid and then increments their streak by 1. The goal schema participants section is as follows :

```
 participants: [{
        userID:  {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        userName: {
            type: String,
            maxlength: 100,
            required : true
        },
        streak: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            default: 0
        } 
    }]
```

However, when I try to run this function for a user that has a streak of 0 or doesn't have a streak field, the streak counter is set to 2 within the database. The function is only getting called once, and I've tried playing around with $upsert and $new to no avail. Does anyone have any idea how this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was having the callback which resulted in the increment operation getting called twice.

Solution :

```
await Goal.updateOne({_id: goalID, 'participants.userID': uid}, {$inc: {'participants.$.streak': 1}}, {}).exec();
```